# Как "за кулисами" реализуется интернет-поток?

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, любой-язык, osi

Ковыряя `ASP.NET` проект я задумался, а как за кулисами реализуются интернет-потоки.

Скажем, контроллеры имеют метод в который можно передать поток байт и вызывающая сторона начнет их скачивать.

Браузер многократно посылается запрос на одну и ту же ссылку, запрашивая определенный `Range`через заголовок?

Язык меня особо не интересует, так как реализация там скорее всего будет +- идентичная.

Рещюмируя, вопросы по части взаимодействия вот такие:

1. Когда браузер получает ответ от веб-сервера, то Content еще динамически докачивается?
2. Существует ли Content как таковой или это абстракция и при обращении к нему браузер отправляет на каждую порцию запрос "Дай мне N байт".

P.S Я исходники `.NET CORE` стянул, что бы посмотреть реализацию, но пока руки не дошли. Быть может кто-то уже разбирал это и может на пальцах рассказать...

Comment: Что такое "интернет-поток"?

Comment: Asp.net - это фреймворк. Браузер общается с веб сервером, веб сервер уже обрабатывает запросы с помощью фреймворка. Во времена iis это называлось isapi.

Comment: [A Low Level Look at ASP.NET Architecture](https://www.codemag.com/Article/0511061/A-Low-Level-Look-at-ASP.NET-Architecture)

Comment: @tym32167 Вот мне интересно, как браузер договаривается с веб-сервером. Скажем, браузер перешл по ссылке. ASP.NET в ответ ему выплевывает поток байтов. Вот с этого момента, как браузер кусками запрашивает у веб-сервера данные? HTTP, если я не ошибаюсь, не поддерживает состояния. Браузер каждый раз шлет запрос на одну и ту же ссылку с заголовком Range?

Comment: @user7860670 Данные, которые передает веб-сервер, допустим, браузеру. Если работать через HttpClient в .NET, то можно обратится к Response.Content и читать поток по байтово.

Comment: Тогда ваш вопрос не относится к asp.net, он больше о модели OSI и спецификации http

Comment: Вот на Wiki https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 написано, что веб-браузер может запрашивать куски через Range. Однако, не совсем понимаю на счет первого запроса. Вот сервер вернул Content. Как я понимаю, если файл большой, то туда каким-то образом дописываются данные или сначала возвращается описание размеров файла, а потом браузер говорит "Дай мне кусок такой-то длинны"?

Answer (score 2):

"За кулисами", если я правильно понял вопрос, это реализуется через [Transfer-Encoding: chunked](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding):

> Chunked transfer encoding — механизм передачи данных в протоколе передачи гипертекста (HTTP), позволяющий надёжно доставлять данные от
>   сервера клиенту (чаще всего клиентскому web-браузеру) без
>   необходимости заранее знать точный размер всего тела HTTP-сообщения.
>   Это достигается разбиением сообщения на небольшие части (chunks), а
>   затем передачей каждой части с указанием только её размера (в
>   шестнадцатеричном виде). Окончание передачи сообщения определяется
>   наличием последней части с нулевой длиной. Такой механизм позволяет
>   передать динамически сформированные объекты, для которых нельзя
>   заранее определить размер. Он стал доступен только начиная с HTTP
>   версии 1.1 (HTTP/1.1).
>
> Без механизма сhunked transfer encoding с каждым HTTP-пакетом
>   необходимо указывать заголовок Content-Length, чтобы клиент мог найти
>   конец передаваемого сообщения.

Comment: Хорошо, а без использования Chunked transfer encoding, как это добро работает? Просто, обычно, браузер всегда знает длину файла => Content-Length, как я понимаю, веб-сервер передает файл целиком. И вот тут у меня возникает вопрос: Когда браузер получает ответ от сервера, то Content все еще может подкачиваться?

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну разумеется, условно говоря оно в любом случае будет работать в виде "заголовок" -> "контент". Т.е. если ты запрашиваешь какую-то картинку то вернется заголовок, например "200 OK" затем будет размер контента (опционально) и потом идёт сам контент. Т.е. это в любом случае идёт в виде единого потока данных. Главное отличие chunked в том, что им можно передавать контент размер которого заранее неизвестен (я думал интересен именно этот кейс).

Comment: А когда ответ приходит, то контент уже готов или он на ходу докачивается?

Comment: @iluxa1810 ответ это и есть всегда "поток", в голове идёт заголовок поэтому и есть возможность прочитать его первым и понять что нас ждёт дальше и корректно это обработать, сразу за заголовком начинается контент.

Comment: Ну т.е браузер получает зголовок с размером, далее обращается к контенту, который все еще может передаваться с сервера?

Comment: @iluxa1810 дополнительного обращения к контенту не происходит, ответ на запрос один он содержит и заголовок и содержимое в одном ответном потоке.